# How to filter conditional entries from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I am currently building a web scraping tool using Python, where I am pulling recordings from a sound archive website. The website provides an API to facilitate this. Below is the code for extracting the data:

```
import requests

url = "https://xeno-canto.org/api/2/recordings?query=emberiza+pusilla"
response = requests.get(url)
json_data = response.json()

num_recordings = json_data['numRecordings']  # number of recordings retrieved
recordings = json_data['recordings']  # meta data and recording links from xeno-canto
```

The num_recordings is just summary data for the search. What I am really interested in is the recordings variable.

I have tried a variety of ways to extract each recording entry from the recordings variable. I tried a for loop, which didn't work. I have tried a list comprehension, that again hasn't worked. I am not sure which of those to post so I am posting neither. I am so lost, and any help from anyone will be appreciated.

What I need to do is extract specific key:value pairs from the recordings list (notes: recordings is a list of dictionaries). I want to make it so I can download each of the respective entries that meet a given set of criteria, such as:

- the country where the recording was made
- the type of recording: It must be a song, I am not interested in calls
- I want to drop the unnecessary key value pairs, but no matter how much I search the web no where seems to have a simple answer on how to do this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm which language this is?

Comment: It's in python, I have edited it to reflect this. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the data into Pandas DataFrame and then do filtering afterwards. For example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://xeno-canto.org/api/2/recordings?query=emberiza+pusilla"
json_data = requests.get(url).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(json_data['recordings'])
print(df[['id', 'type', 'en', 'cnt', 'url']].head())
```

Prints:

```
       id                                type              en       cnt                      url
0  809482                                song  Little Bunting    Sweden  //xeno-canto.org/809482
1  790878                                song  Little Bunting     China  //xeno-canto.org/790878
2  779437                                song  Little Bunting    Sweden  //xeno-canto.org/779437
3  771411  flight call, nocturnal flight call  Little Bunting   Denmark  //xeno-canto.org/771411
4  770115                                call  Little Bunting  Mongolia  //xeno-canto.org/770115
```

---

Then to list all songs from Sweden:

```py
mask = df['type'].str.contains('song') & df['cnt'].eq('Sweden')
print(df.loc[mask, ['id', 'type', 'en', 'cnt', 'url']])
```

Prints:

```
         id  type              en     cnt                      url
0    809482  song  Little Bunting  Sweden  //xeno-canto.org/809482
2    779437  song  Little Bunting  Sweden  //xeno-canto.org/779437
25   571116  song  Little Bunting  Sweden  //xeno-canto.org/571116
109  667088  song  Little Bunting  Sweden  //xeno-canto.org/667088
224   27593  song  Little Bunting  Sweden   //xeno-canto.org/27593
225   26686  song  Little Bunting  Sweden   //xeno-canto.org/26686
243  663460  song  Little Bunting  Sweden  //xeno-canto.org/663460
```

---

EDIT: To download the files:

```py
mask = df['type'].str.contains('song') & df['cnt'].eq('Sweden')
for id_, url in zip(df.loc[mask, 'id'], df.loc[mask, 'file']):
    print(f'Downloading {url}')
    with open(f'{id_}.wav', 'wb') as f_out:
        f_out.write(requests.get(url).content)
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! And would I be able to call requests.get on a column to download all the associated .wav files that the 'file' key links to?

Comment: @whorrodwi Yes, of course. I've updated my answer and added example how you could iterate the dataframe and download the files.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is incredibly helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can do basic comprehensions with criteria. For example first do a list comprehension with the criteria of dictionaries you want to keep:

```
country = "Sweden"
recording_type ="song"
relevant_recordings = [x for x in recordings if x['cnt'] == country and x['type'] == recording_type]
```

and then filter out any fields you don't want (technically creating new dictionaries without the fields) with a dictionary comprehension inside a list comprehension like this:

```
unnecessary_keys = ['lat', 'lng', 'lat']
final_data = [{k:v for k,v in x.items() if x not in unnecessary_keys} for x in relevant_recordings]
```

You could of course do both in the same operation, but that would probably be more difficult to read:

```
final_data = [{k:v for k,v in x.items() if x not in unnecessary_keys} for x in relevant_recordings if x['cnt'] == country and x['type'] == recording_type]
```